Multiple issues and errors with tensor flow array / matrix / tensor shape and data manipulation
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
from datasets import load_dataset
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Input
import random
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from datasets import load_dataset

from datasets import load_dataset
dataset = load_dataset("csv", data_files="bitcoin_daily/data_btc.csv", split="train")

input_shape = (3, 6)

def GetRandomThirtyDays(dataset):
    
    dates = dataset["date"]
    random_date = random.choice(dates)
    
    # Find the index of the random date
    random_date_index = dates.index(random_date)
    
    # Get the last 30 days starting from the random date
    start_index = max(0, random_date_index - 5)  # Ensure the start index is not negative
    last_30_days_dates = dates[start_index:random_date_index]  
    
    # Check if all dates exist in the dataset
    for date in last_30_days_dates:
        if date not in dates:
            return GetRandomThirtyDays()  # If any date is missing, recursively call the function to get a new random set of 30 days
    
    # Save the indices of the last 30 days
    last_30_days_indices = list(range(start_index, random_date_index + 1))
    
    return  last_30_days_indices, random_date_index + 1
def VerifyIndexExists(dataset, index):
    try:
        dataset["price"][index]
        return dataset["price"][index]
    except:
        return False
def GetSellPrices(dataset, indices, ):
    # Get the sell prices for the last 30 days using the indices
    DataDictionary = []
    Destroyed = False
    for index in indices:
        # Get the sell price, market_caps and the volumes for the current index IF it exists and return it. If anything is nil (destroyed)

        try:
            if dataset["price"][index] == None:
                Destroyed = True
                break
            sell_price = dataset["price"][index]
            if dataset["market_caps"][index] == None:
                Destroyed = True
                break
            market_cap = dataset["market_caps"][index]
            if dataset["total_volumes"][index] == None:
                Destroyed = True
                break
            volume = dataset["total_volumes"][index]
            DataDictionary.append([sell_price, market_cap, volume])
        except:
            Destroyed = True
    
    return DataDictionary, Destroyed

def Get30DayData(dataset):
    indices, answerIndex = GetRandomThirtyDays(dataset) #Get 30 random dates   
    ThirtyDayDataDictionary, Destroyed = GetSellPrices(dataset, indices)
    # go back recursively if we are destroyed
    PredictionAnswer = VerifyIndexExists(dataset, answerIndex)
    if not PredictionAnswer:
        return Get30DayData(dataset)
    if Destroyed:
        return Get30DayData(dataset)
    return ThirtyDayDataDictionary, PredictionAnswer


model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    layers.Input(shape=input_shape),  # Input layer with specified shape
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'),
    layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mean_squared_error", metrics=["accuracy"])

X_training = []
answer = []
for _ in tqdm(range(20)):
    X, y = Get30DayData(dataset)
    if X:
        X_training.append(X)
        answer.append(y)

X_training_np = np.array(X_training)
answer = np.array(X_training)
   
model.fit(X_training_np, answer, epochs=300, batch_size=1, verbose=0)
model.evaluate(X_training_np, answer, verbose=2)


This is my code and I'm getting multiple random shape errors. I am a tensorflow beginner. The reason Im only using the past 5 days of data is because it's easier to read as a log. Help would be appreciated!
Im trying to train an ANN on a 3 by 5 list to capture all the data of the past days using a float as the prediction.

Full error message(s)?

Here is one:
Incompatible shapes: [20,6,3] vs. [20,1]
[[{{node compile_loss/mean_squared_error/sub}}]] [Op:__inference_one_step_on_iterator_16743].
I can't post the whole error as the tracebacks go beyond the character limit.

I could not get the other errors to come up now but I might post them later if possible.

X_training_np = np.array(X_training)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (20,) + inhomogeneous part.

X_training is a 'ragged' list, and can't be made into numpy array.  Check the size of all elements.  When you get 'incompatible shapes', make sure you understand the why of those shapes.  And the numpy broadcasting rules.

Errors with full traceback are best added to the question.  Comments are too short and lose formatting.  Unless the inputs are simple we cannot run your code, so we can only go by the infornation you provide.  No information == no help
